# inequality $ [f(G):f(f(G))]\leq [G:f(G)] $

Tags: group-theory

Let $ G $ be a group and $ f:G\to G $ be a homomorphism. Prove that $ [f(G):f(f(G))]\leq [G:f(G)] $.

What I know is that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then $ [H:H\cap K]\leq [G:K] $ and $ [G:H\cap K]\leq [G:H][G:K]$, which I could not make work. I tried to prove that $ f(f(G))=f(G) $ but I think it is not true in general. Any hint?

Comment: Well, it isn't generally true that $f(G)=f(f(G))$:  let $G$ be the Klein group of order $4$, $g,h\in G$ two distinct elements of order $2$ and define $f(g)=h$, $f(h)=e$.  Then  $f(G)\simeq \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ but $f(f(G))=<e>$.

Answer (score 1):

My original proof only works for finite group, thus is not good. We may take another way.
Suppose for $i\in I$, $h_i f(f(G))$ are disjoint left cosets of $f(f(G))$ in $f(G)$. Since $h_i\in f(G)$, we may assume $h_i=f(g_i)$. Now we prove $g_i f(G)$ is disjoint left cosets of $f(G)$ in $G$. It suffices to show that $g_i^{-1}g_j\not\in f(G)$ for $i\not=j$. Suppose on the contrary, if $g_i^{-1}g_j\in f(G)$, we have $f(g_i^{-1})f(g_j)\in f(f(G))$, i.e., $h_i^{-1}h_j\in f(f(G))$, contradicting the disjointness of $h_i f(f(G))$.

Now choose $h_i$ properly so that $h_i f(f(G))$ is a left coset decompostion. We have $[f(G):f(f(G))]=|I|$. But $g_i f(G)$ are disjoint left cosets of $f(G)$ in $G$, so $[G:f(G)]\geq |I|$. Thus we're done.

Comment: I tried to figure it out but did not see the equivalence between $ |\ker f|\geq |\ker f_{f(G)}|  $ and $[f(G):f(f(G))]\leq [G:f(G)]$.

Comment: @Jax It only works for finite group. My mistake :( I have posted a new answer.

Comment: That was a good point. Can you tell me, please, why it works for finite groupe? Thank you so much

Comment: For finite groups, from the first isomorphism theorem we have $|G| / \lvert \ker f \rvert = |G/\ker f| = |f(G)|$, so $\lvert \ker f \rvert = |G| / |f(G)| = [G:f(G)]$.

Answer (score 0):

In general let $G/H$ denote the set of (left) cosets of $H$ in $G$, so that $[G:H] = |G/H|$. Show that $gf(G) \mapsto f(g)f(f(G))$ defines a well-defined function from $G/f(G)$ to $f(G)/f(f(G))$ and that it is surjective.